# VBA Excel: Cell value string concatenation does not work

Tags: vba, excel

Could you please assist me with the following problem. All I want to do is "clean" a list by adding "0" in front of every cellphone number. This is my code:

```
Sub ListCleaner_CleanCellPhoneNumbers()
Dim selectedRange As Range
Set selectedRange = getSelectedRange()

Dim i As Integer
Dim max As Integer
i = 1
max = selectedRange.Rows.Count

While i <= max
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = selectedRange.Cells(i)

    ' Get row number
    Dim rowNumber As Integer
    rowNumber = cell.Row

    ' Skip header
    If rowNumber > 1 Then
        If Mid(cell.Value, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
            cell.Value = "0" & cell.Value
        End If
    End If

    i = i + 1
Wend
```

My problem lies in the line 'cell.Value = "0" & cell.Value'. It simply does not add a "0" in front. If I do the following 'cell.Value = "0" & "Hello world"' it works just fine. I also checked and the cell.Value is properly accessed etc.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I do not think the issue is in the fact that I use a 0 in front. I tried with other numbers as well as characters, all formatted to text etc. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this by using a combinations of the suggested answers. Thanks to @vba4all and @dared for the responses. +1

Here was my solution:

```
cell.Value = "'0" & LTrim(cell.text)
```

I had to use a ' before the 0, and use the cell.text instead of the value. The LTrim is used to eliminate leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell is type of number it will remove all the zeros in the begining.
If the cell is typeof text it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If phone number always has the same length (for example 9 numbers), you can change NumberFormat as states in below code. It will change only numbers, so your headers are safe :)

```
Sub ListCleaner_CleanCellPhoneNumbers()

Dim selectedRange As Range
Set selectedRange = getSelectedRange()

        selectedRange.NumberFormat = "000000000"

End Sub
```